# Handle all thread exception in Winforms

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have following test code,

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread obj = new Thread(exception);
        obj.Start();
    }
    void exception()
    {
        try
        {
            int i = 0;
            int k = i / i;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int k = i / i;
    }
```

And my main code is like this

```
 [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.ThreadException += Form1_UIThreadException;
        Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    private static void Form1_UIThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception");
    }

    private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
       // MessageBox.Show("Exception UI");
    }
```

Even I have handled both the exceptions application is crashing on thread exception.

Whether any correction I need to do for handle thread exception as well ?

Comment: Maybe *"To catch exceptions that occur in threads not created and owned by Windows Forms, use the UnhandledException event handler."* https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't process an unhandled CurrentDomain exception and have the program continue after you've processed it.

By the time the `UnhandledException` event is raised, the UI thread's stack has already been unwound too far to allow the program to continue.

As the documentation for [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> It allows the application to log information about the exception before the system default handler reports the exception to the user and terminates the application.

If you inspect the value of `e.IsTerminating` when you receive the event notification, you'll see that it's `true`.

Your only recourse is to handle exceptions within the button handler.

Note that the reason the program can continue after the `ThreadException` is caught is that only that thread's stack has been unwound, which doesn't (directly) affect the UI thread.